# How to create a Like button in a "display:none" context?

Tags: firefox, facebook-like

The Like button plugin doesn't appear, if one of its containers is `display:none` when the page loads, and made visible later with `display:block`.

Problem detected in Firefox (my version 15.0.1) only.

What can I do?

Comment: Dude, seriously, add your code to your question.

Comment: You can see this problem right on one of my pages http://execute.by/articles/104. Press bottom right link "поделиться" to show hidden element. In other browsers except FF it works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is the reason of this bug (FB or FF), but I've solve that problem by show my element by default in FF only:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {#exe-article-social-tools { display: block; }}
```

Answer (score 3):

when you make the element visible, you should add your fb like plugin to dom

IE

```
<div id="showfb">mouseoverme</div>
<div style="display:none" id="facebutton"></div>

<script>
      var fbbutton = document.getElementById("facebutton");
      document.getElementById("showfb").onmouseover = function(){
          // first visible
          fbbutton.style.display='block';
          // then add fb html5
          fbbutton.innerHTML = '<div class="fb-like" ......... ></div>';
      };
</script>
```

in alternative, try

```
width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden
```

instead of

```
display:none
```

and

```
width:auto;height:auto;overflow:visible
```

instead of

```
display:block
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just want solve that problem in FF and guess it no good to do additional script activity for all browsers. Waiting for better decision

Comment: do with opacity:0 instead of visibility:hidden/display:none

Comment: But in case using opacity:0 the height of element doesn't null & there is unnecessary empty space appears

Comment: try with visibility:collapse instead of display:none (works in firefox but not on IE, then you need some css hacks)

Comment: May be it is good, but how to avoid empty space of element? See the site now, I've used visibility:collapse for my element

Comment: forget about visibility:collapse, try `width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden` instead of `display:none`, and `width:auto;height:auto;overflow:visible` instead of `display:block`

Comment: `width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;` doesn't hide element after loading

Comment: hi, provide an example page with width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden please

Comment: Having same issue.  The width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden; fix works in FF but the same problem still happens is IE9. My guess is Facebook is deliberetly looking if the element is visible or not for some reason, and injecting the width:0;height:0 on its own span.  Might have to move to scripting fixes & DOM manipulation. Was hoping it could just be fixed via css.

Comment: try position:absolute;left:-10000px; when not visible, position:static;left:0; when visible

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

The fb-root tag

**The JavaScript SDK requires the fb-root element to be present in the page.
The fb-root element must not be hidden using display: none or visibility: hidden, or some parts of the SDK will not work properly in Internet Explorer.**

Answer (score 0):

It took me an entire day to figure it out, but **being logged in on Facebook with a "test user" renders the like button invisible**. In my case, I was always logged in with my test user on Firefox, while logged out / logged in with my regular Facebook user in Chrome (and I initially thought this was a browser issue).

However, the **solution** was as easy as loggin off the test user.

It is specified in the FB docs that not all features are enabled for test users (and the like button is one of those features), but I'd thought that it would at least get rendered.
Anyway, I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a number of different invisible divs on my page where `fb-like` buttons was hidden. When one of div shown, no `fb-like` button appears in it. Solution worked for me is to relaunch FB.init manually each time when invisible div reveals.
FB is a global function being added into your window object since you call for remote facebook api by url like `http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js`. So since this remote script attached to your DOM you can run something like

```
FB.init({
        appId      : '346094915460000', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add like button html5 code to the DOM and then run the FB parser again to generate the like button:

```
fbbutton.innerHTML = '<div class="fb-like" ... ></div>';
FB.XFBML.parse();
```